# How to delete certain words from a .text file on button click?

Tags: c#, file-io

What i'm trying to do is delete certain text from a .text file. For example:

I have a .text file with the following text.

```
Hello
This
Is <----- I would like to delete this line from the file.
My
Text
```

I have tried to use the following code:

```
    private void DeleteButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Contact.");
        }
        else
        {

            comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            File.Delete(comboBox2.SelectedItem + ".txt");
            string SelectedItem = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string empty = "";
           string Readcurrentcontacts = File.ReadAllText(contactpath);
           Readcurrentcontacts.Replace(SelectedItem, empty);
        }
    }
```

With no succesful results. If you need any further information please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your question "Why `String.Replace` returns value instead of changing string in-place"? (`Readcurrentcontacts = Readcurrentcontacts.Replace(SelectedItem, empty);`

Comment: -1 code is GUI code with text in a combo box! Title talks about files. Make your mind up.

Answer (score 1):

The [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) methods would be useful here:

```
string SelectedItem = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

var allLines = File.ReadLines(contactpath)

// Linq filter to exclude selected item
var newLines = allLines.Where(line => line != SelectedItem);

File.WriteAllLines(contactpath, newLines);
```

Note that [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) is a Linq extension method that takes an IEnumerable as input, and returns a subset based on the predicate that you provide.  So, the line above takes the input (all lines in the file), and returns all lines that are not equal to `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response, i'm not really sure what `// Linq filter to exclude selected item` means, could you explain that? And I'm also not sure what `.Where(line => line != SelectedItem);` means, could you explain that as well? I copy and pasted this code in my program to see if it would work and it gave the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'`

Comment: @Shaquanda my mistake -- `newLines` should be of type `IEnumerable<string>`.  I've added a bit of explanation to my answer ... basically it selects all lines except the ones that are equal to "SelectedItem".

Comment: When I run this I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` :(